# How to redirect user after facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I am developing a game which requires user to login and then uses the login details to update the leaderboard. But the problem is that after the user logs in, the login dialog does not get closed automatically and the user is not redirected to the game. Here is the code which is taken from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#login)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    shepResponse = response;
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') 
      testAPI();
    }
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try not wrapping FB.Event.subscribe and testAPI() inside the fbAsyncInit function.

Also try auth.statusChange instead of auth.authResponseChange

var fb_handleStatusChange = function(response) {

     if (response.authResponse) {

     // user logged in

    } else {

     // not logged in or logged out

}

}

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fb_handleStatusChange);

Also, i think that the login redirect should be to a page that has this code and is listening for status change. I would not redirect back to the same page as the one used for login.